# Am I using groupby.sum() correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've the following code, and a problem in the new_df["SUM"] line:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_excel(r"D:\Tesina\Proteoma Humano\Tablas\uno - copia.xlsx")

#df =  pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['C9JLR9','O95391', 'P05114',"P14866"], 'SEQ': ['1..100,182..250,329..417,490..583', '1..100,206..254,493..586', '1..100', "1..100,284..378" ]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame

df["SEQ"] = df["SEQ"].replace("\.\."," ", regex =True)
new_df = df.assign(SEQ=df.SEQ.str.split(',')).explode('SEQ')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    new_df['delta'] = new_df['SEQ'].map(lambda x: (int(x.split()[1])+1)-int(x.split()[0]) if x.split()[0] != '1' else (int(x.split()[1])+1))
new_df["SUM"] = new_df.groupby(["ID"]).sum().reset_index(drop=True) #Here's the error, even though I can't see where
df2 = new_df.groupby(["ID","SUM"], sort=False)["SEQ"].apply((lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))).reset_index(name="SEQ")
```

To give some context, what it does is the following: grabs every line with the same ID, separates the numbers with a "," in between, does some math with those numbers (that's where the "delta" (which i know it's not a delta) line gets involved), and finally sums up all the "delta" for each ID, grouping them all by their original ID, so I maintain the same numbers of rows.

And, when I use a sample of the data (the one that´s commented at the beginning), it works perfectly, giving me the ouptut that I wish:

```
       ID  SUM                            SEQ
0  C9JLR9  353  1 100,182 250,329 417,490 583
1  O95391  244          1 100,206 254,493 586
2  P05114  101                          1 100
3  P14866  196                  1 100,284 378
```

But, when I aply it on my Excel file (that has 10471 rows), the groupby.sum() line doesn't work as it's supposed to (I've already checked everything else, I know the error is within that line).
This is the output that I receive:

```
           ID  SUM                            SEQ
0      C9JLR9   39  1 100,182 250,329 417,490 583
1      O95391   20          1 100,206 254,493 586
2      P05114   33                          1 100
4      P98177   21                  1 100,176 246
```

You can clearly see that the SUM values differ (and are not correct at all). I haven't been able to figure out where those numbers come from, also. It's really weird.

Comment: IIUC use `new_df["SUM"] = new_df.groupby("ID")["delta"].transform("sum")` instead.

Comment: It worked well on the sample dict, I'm running over the whole file. If it works I'll let you know, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, the solution was provided in the comments: I had to change the line with the following:

```
new_df["SUM"] = new_df.groupby("ID")["delta"].transform("sum")
```